# UICollectionView custom layouts

Tags: layout, ios6, uicollectionview

Hi I am beginning iOS development, and was playing around with UICollectionView. I was just wondering how you could achieve this type of layout. As shown below:
The idea is to have like a main news article in the big cell. Just confused how I am suppose to get two cells in the 2nd column. Much appreciated!

[image: UICollectionView layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create custom class which will act as layout for your collection view. This class will child class for UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Then you can override below two methods and can create your own custom layout as you want.

```
  - (NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
  - (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path
```

UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes is class which will deal with cell position, frame, Zindex etc

You can also use below properties.

```
 collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
 collectionView:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
```

Comment: I have also implemented similar layout but in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` considers old visible rect as the delegate method gets called before `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` which results in blinking (reloading) of visible cells in my app. How did you avoid this issue.